# Deploying Azure Logic App and Service Bus Template

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-rm-template

I'm tryinng to deploy a logic app connected to a service bus template, but I want when I deploy it, still have the connection "alive". How do I do it? Because what I've done an error shows up into the portal, with status *Error*.

[image]

This is part of my template code:

```
"variables": {
   "defaultSASKeyName": "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
   "authRuleResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationRules', parameters('namespaces_TestTemplateServiceBus_name'), variables('defaultSASKeyName'))]",
   "sbVersion": "2017-04-01"
 },

"outputs": {
   "NamespaceConnectionString": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listkeys(variables('authRuleResourceId'), variables('sbVersion')).primaryConnectionString]"
   },
   "SharedAccessPolicyPrimaryKey": {
       "type": "string",
       "value": "[listkeys(variables('authRuleResourceId'), variables('sbVersion')).primaryKey]"
   }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the Connection String parameter from the API connection (to your Service Bus). When you create the Logic App it will also create the API connection. That API connection is shown in the screenshot. You should add the Connection String of the RootManageSharedAccessKey to the Api Connection (click the orange banner "Parameter value missing.")